# Unable to download pdf file from the server in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file, pdf, download

I am using the following codes in my controller to download pdf files which are stored in a folder inside application folder in codeigniter. 
In the view page I have a button, upon clicking it, it redirects to this controller and then it download the file. It downloads blank page(pdf).
Looking forward to any suggestion.

```
 $filePath = APPPATH.'invoice/'."Let's Sunday#".$this->uri->segment(4).".pdf";
        if(!empty($filePath) && file_exists($filePath)){ 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .$filePath); 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
        flush(); 
        $fp = fopen($filePath, "r");
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            echo fread($fp, 65536);
            flush(); 
        } 
        fclose($fp); }else{echo "file does not exist";}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `$pdfFilePath` ?

Comment: And also, on `filesize($file)` where does `$file` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have in a download section within a CodeIgniter app:

```
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filePath).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
    readfile($filePath);
    flush(); 
    exit;
}
```

The differences are in the ordering of the headers (which likely doesn't matter), the inclusion of the expires and pragma headers, and the `Content-Disposition` using the full basename.

The naming convention on that PDF filename might cause an issue...something else to test out.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name in `Content-Disposition` to filename only instead of full path